# Can I enable or disable devices in batch script without any dev tool?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, hid

Can I enable or disable devices without DevCon.exe or I have to use that?
I don't want to use devcon.exe, personally I don't want to install another devtool for a simple function what windows can do.
If there any other way to enable and disable a HID device in batch script please let me know.

Comment: `SC` command works on drivers as well. `Sc /?`.

Comment: you can through the WMIC command - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/disable-win32-pnpentity

Answer (score 2):

with this you can see the state of the device:

```
wmic path Win32_PnPEntity where "name='Microsoft Print to PDF'" get /format:value
```

or all devices:

```
wmic path Win32_PnPEntity get /format:csv
```

to disable device:

```
wmic path Win32_PnPEntity where "name='Microsoft Print to PDF'" call disable
```

to enable device

```
wmic path Win32_PnPEntity where "name='Microsoft Print to PDF'" call enable
```

Both enable and disable methods will return a **ReturnValue** which will indicate if the operation was successful and **rebootNeeded** that indicates if the machines needs a restart in order to apply changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use PowerShell, you can make use of [`Get-PnpDevice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/get-pnpdevice?view=win10-ps), [`Enable-PnpDevice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/enable-pnpdevice?view=win10-ps), and [`Disable-Pnpdevice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/disable-pnpdevice?view=win10-ps) to perform these actions. For instance, to list out PnP devices:

```
PS C:\Users\example> Get-Pnpdevice | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -match "microphone"}

Status     Class           FriendlyName
------     -----           ------------
Unknown    AudioEndpoint   Microphone (Headset)
Unknown    AudioEndpoint   Microphone (Webcam)
```